# Antidebug plugin for ollydbg 2.01

Tags: ollydbg

Can't find any working anti-antidebug plugin for olly 2.01. Maybe anyone can give me one?

Comment: Not really on-topic, given the nature of the question, but how about https://bitbucket.org/NtQuery/scyllahide/ ...?